# How to check request.form.get value null or not in python flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

**I'm starting simple CURD operation with python Flask framework and i want to when user submit form how to check users selected value null or not?**

*I was tried this*

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        Name = request.form.get('Name')
        city = request.form.get('City')
        if Name == '' and city == '':
            print('its null')
        else:
             print('success')
```

but when i'm submit without fill any value its give output

```
success
```

i'm also try None and null but can't work.

Comment: `Name` should be `None`. Likely you're sending a space or some other non-printable character in your HTML.

Comment: <input type="text"  name="Name"> for name and     <select  name="City">
                                                <option value="">Select</option> for city

Comment: Please add your HTML form to the question.

Comment: Use the truthy check of `name` and `city`: `if not name and not city: # ...`

Answer (score 3):

i tried your above method..it is working for me."remember" is checkbox input type in my html.

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['POST'])
def login_validate():
    email=request.form['email']
    password=request.form['pass']
    remember=request.form.get('remember')
    if remember:
       print "present"
    else:
       print "not present"
```